# How can I access to a second level information in a JSON response with RxJs library?

Tags: json, rxjs, observable

The `SelectAllPaged(UserQ)` method returns an `Observable` that contains the response of an API that query users from a table. To this Observable I execute the `subscribe()` method to take the response and make it as interface type `IUserQ` (1st level of the JSON content). What I need, in addition to the information of the 1st level, is the information contained in the 2nd level, that is, the list of users, `lstUser`, which respects the `IUser` interface.

I attached an inspection here, [Debugging an RxJS observable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deTzb.png), that I did during debugging on the `UserQ` constant. Any info helps me, thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your response using map operator

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

SelectAllPaged(UserQ).pipe(
  map((response:IUserQ) =>  response.lstUser)
).subscribe((usersList:IUser[]) => console.log("users list", usersList ))
```